# Git: trying to remove a local branch, but permission denied because of a locked file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git, gitlab

On my Linux server there were several git branches I wanted to remove. I used `git branch -D branche_name` and deleted all these branches except for one. For this one branch called `feat/implement-h` I get the error:

> “error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/feat/implement-h': Unable to
>   create '/data/web/xxx/xxx/.git/refs/heads/feat/implement-h.lock':
>   Permission denied”.

I recently got access to this Linux server, which has been used for several years but I didn't have access before. Any idea how I could remove this branch?

Comment: Did you check file ower and permissions? It sounds like something in the `.git` dir is owned by some other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Halfgaar says it is probably a permissions problem.  I have found that files belonging to `root` tend to accumulate in my git repositories, albeit very slowly.  In my case they often seem to be in

```
.git/objects
```

and don't seem to cause problems there.  However, if a `lock` file ends up belonging to `root` that is obviously going to be an issue.  You can check for such files with

```
find ~/your/git/dir -group root -ls
```

My assumption is that, very occasionally, when Git throws an error, the ownership information can become corrupted.

Comment: Thanks @Ioris, it returns the 2 lines below. Indeed, root seems to be owner. I'm a newbie to this: how could I solve this?

`1204263      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 May  6 16:49 /your/.git/refs/heads/feat/`
--- 
`1201452      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           41 May  6 16:49 /your/.git/refs/heads/feat/implement-h`

Comment: As ```root``` you need to change the ownership for the files, e.g. ```chown nick:users /your/.git/refs/heads/feat/implement-h```.  The best thing is probably to do this with ```find```, e.g. ```find ~/your/git/dir -group root -exec chown nick:user {} \;```.  Here I'm assuming that your primary group is ```users```, but it could be something else (see ```id nick```).  I'm also assuming you can log in directly as ```root```.  However, if you are, say, logged into Ubuntu as ```nick```, you will need to use ```sudo``` in front of either of the commands above.